# How do I get a Rectangle drawn on an adorner to scale with the Image element its bound to when the window size is changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, adorner

I'm using a rectangle drawn on an adorner to mark a region of interest on an image. The issue is that if I resize the window, the rectangle doesn't change size.

I'm new to WPF, so I've done a bunch of research, googling what I can with multiple different search terms. I actually just learned adorners that way, and I've gotten this far on that, but I've hit a wall on how to finish this last piece. I know that my problem is based in the size of the rectangle, but I don't know what to capture/look for to adjust it, since wpf resizes the actual image object on window resize, so there's no scale factor to look at.

Here's the XAML for the application I'm testing things in.

```
<Window x:Class="TestingAdorners.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingAdorners"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <Image Name="Btn" Source="nyan.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
            </AdornerDecorator>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

The adorner class:

```
    class RoiAdorner : Adorner
    {
        public Rect rectangle = new Rect();
        public RoiAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
        {
            rectangle.Height = 30;
            rectangle.Width = 100;
            IsHitTestVisible = false;

        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Green, 5);

            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, pen, rectangle);

        }
    }
```

And the Xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(Btn).Add(new RoiAdorner(Btn));

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

The desired result is that the rectangle scales with the image object so that it always covers the same region of the image. The problem is I don't know how to capture a scale factor to scale it up and down as the window resizes.

Update: After thinking through Frenchy's suggestion I realized the answer is simply: "Normalize your coordinates"

Comment: This rectangle is just a green rectangle on top of an image? If the rectangle was part of the thing stretched then it would just stretch with it. That's the effect you want? Why is the image in an adornerdecorator?

Comment: The adornerDecorator creates and manages an adornerLayer, without which you cannot attach an adorner to use as an overlay. This is a separate project I made to learn Adorners. In reality, It will be used to highlight areas of interest on a different image, but yes the desired effect is a rectangle overlaid on the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just adapt your render method like this:

```
class RoiAdorner : Adorner
{
    public double factorX = 0d;
    public double factorY = 0d;
    public Rect rectangle = new Rect();
    public RoiAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
    {

        rectangle.Height = 30;
        rectangle.Width = 100;
        IsHitTestVisible = false;

    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        if (factorY == 0)
            factorY =  rectangle.Height / AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height;
        if (factorX == 0)
            factorX = rectangle.Width / AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width;
        var r = new Rect(new Size(AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Width * factorX, AdornedElement.DesiredSize.Height * factorY));
        //Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, new Pen(Brushes.Red, 5), r);

    }
```

this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize gives you the size of image.

Comment: Almost what I want. I'm trying to select just an area of the image, for example the image I'm testing with is Nyan Cat, and the region of interest could be, say, the head. So when I scale the image, the rectangle, which is only around the head, should also scale, so It stays only around the head.

Comment: you just add factors scale for width and height, see the answer modified. foolowing your sample you trap the part of image beginning at 0,0

Comment: That could work, but I'll be starting with a region I know I need to draw around, without knowing desired size ahead of time, capturing the exact region to begin with becomes difficult. I think I need some way to draw in what almost amounts to a UV space, where everything is 0-1. I've put a realization in my Initial Post.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would use is to render the picture and rectangle to the same thing. Then that one thing is stretched, scaled or whatever.

One way to do this would be to use a DrawingImage.  Drawing methods are extremely efficient if rather low level.

```
    <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <Image Name="img" Stretch="Uniform">
                <Image.Source>
                    <DrawingImage PresentationOptions:Freeze="True">
                        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                            <DrawingGroup>
                                <ImageDrawing Rect="0,0,595,446" ImageSource="DSC00025.jpg"/>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Green">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,100,30"  />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingGroup>
                        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    </DrawingImage>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </Grid>
```

Another is with a visualbrush.  Controls inherit from visual - this is somewhat higher level coding.

```
    <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
        <AdornerDecorator>
            <Rectangle Name="rec">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <Grid Height="446" Width="595">
                            <Image Source="DSC00025.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
                            <Rectangle Height="30" Width="100" Fill="Green"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </AdornerDecorator>
    </Grid>
```

Note that both of these are quick and dirty illustrations to give you the idea. The image I picked at random off my hard drive is sized 446 * 595.  You could calculate sizes or bind or stretch as suits your requirement best.

Comment: I got it working by essentially using the desiredSize answer above, but this is really good information to have thank you